# How to get DuckDB Postgres extension working with RDS? Docs do not work

Tags: duckdb

I am seeking to connect DuckDB to a Postgres 15.3 Aurora cluster using the Postgres [scanner extension](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.6.1/extensions/postgres_scanner.html).

I can attach the following code to the cluster; however, when I SHOW tables, there are none in the catalog.

```
import duckdb
duckdb.execute('INSTALL postgres;')
duckdb.execute('LOAD postgres;')
duckdb.execute('CALL postgres_attach("dbname=**  \
               user=** password=** \
               host=** \
               port=** connect_timeout=** application_name=**\
               ");')
duckdb.sql('USE main')
duckdb.sql('SHOW TABLES').show()
```

│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ 0 rows  │

I also tried using the single table scan function, but that did not work either.

```
duckdb.sql('SELECT * FROM postgres_scan("dbname=** \
               host=** \
               user=** password=** port=** ", "**", "**") LIMIT 10;').show()
```

Failed to execute query "SELECT pg_is_in_recovery(), pg_export_snapshot(), (select count(*) from pg_stat_wal_receiver)": ERROR:  Function pg_stat_get_wal_receiver() is currently not supported in Aurora.

Any tips on how to get this working?

Comment: Have you tried `SHOW`, or actually querying some of the tables you expect to be there?

Comment: Yes. See code above -> duckdb.sql('USE main') and duckdb.sql('SHOW TABLES').show(). Returns nothing. I also sniffed the query executed by the extension to get the table names that it is rendering the right underlying tables by running the query in DBeaver.

Comment: Closing issue. Resolved via DuckDb GH. Known issue: https://github.com/duckdb/postgres_scanner/issues/129. Force to use latest build: force install postgres_scanner from 'http://nightly-extensions.duckdb.org';

Answer (score 0):

Closing issue. Resolved via DuckDb GH. Known issue: [github.com/duckdb/postgres_scanner/issues/129](https://github.com/duckdb/postgres_scanner/issues/129).

Force to use latest build: force install postgres_scanner from 'nightly-extensions.duckdb.org';